# How to draw custom lines on view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

somebody help me guys,
I made this design using relative and linear layout and after i need this custom lines to indicate total members so please give me any resources to complete this task.

[image: zoom and see this grey lines on image]

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve this problem until now? What are you stuck in?

Comment: A part from the grey lines ,i done all this UI using weight in linear layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#00000f"
    android:rotation="109"
    />
```

You can use `View` to draw lines, to rotate it use, `rotation`: rotation of the view, in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by many resources, after i completed this issues using constraint layout , i think this is new concept which i handled very well and i would like to advise to go on that because their are many features for modification of UI.

[image]